# ComponentWillReceiveProps not triggered

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to the React world.I got stuck on lifecycle methods while doing edit operation.

componentWillReceiveProps method is not triggered even if props are changed.

Here is my code sample.

```
      this.intialState = {
                      name:'',
                      code:'',
                      };
    this.state = this.intialState;




  componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops){
      this.setState({
        name:nextprops.KaraikarEdit.name,
        code:nextprops.KaraikarEdit.code
     })
    }



render() {


 return (
                <div className="form-group">
                <input type= "text"  className="form-control" value={this.state.name}  placeholder="Enter Name" name="name"   onChange = {this.onhandleChange} />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                <input type= "text"  className="form-control" value={this.state.code}  placeholder="Enter Code" name="code"   onChange = {this.onhandleChange} />
                </div>

);
}

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {

             KaraikarEdit: state.KaraikarDetails.editdata
         }
  }


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(KaraikarMasterAdd);
```

I received newprops in KaraikarEdit. but componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method is not fired.

I Know componentWillReceiveProps isn't called on the first render.so i made use of componentDidMount method and in this method i dispatched a action that is useless for this component.Then componentWillReceiveProps is working.

Should i use componentDidMount or componentWillMount method inorder to use componentReceiveProps method? if so what to include in componentDidMount method?

Comment: Yes. I dispatched an action and updated my store with editdata. From state only i got props. But still componentWillReceiveProps is not triggered.

Comment: how are you sure that you received newprops in karaikarEdit? 
componentwillreceiveprops is a event that fires only in Updating scenarios and not in intial render(as you said ). So if your component sent new props after initial render, it definitely works

Comment: sure. I received newprops in KaraikarEdit.

Comment: How did you confirm that you received newProps in karaikarEdit?

Comment: @arthy, what does your app do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the component `state` on mounting you should use `componentDidMount`. `componentWillReceiveProps` is not being invoked on the initial render. Then, to handle updating you'd probably like to use `componentWillUpdate` to set the new state before rendering the updated markup (as it is based on component state).

But! As I can see in your approach - you are unnecessarily copying the store state to the component state. **You can use `this.props` in the `render` function!** In this approach there will be no need for `componentWillReceiveProps` in your implementation.